# The application is unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I am created windows application on my system(windows 8 32 bit).and install into a server2008r2 which is 64 bit.my exe capable for 64 bit.Every day morning i am getting error The application is unable to start correctly (0xc000007b) after that uninstall and install the exe it could be run please help me..plz

Answer (score 0):

Find out if your application or its dependencies have any issues using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). It will help you.

Also the error code `0xc000007b` means `'STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT'`. Check if your disk needs to be fixed.